# Getting points in 2D plane under perspective by real distance using Aruco marker

Tags: opencv, math, computer-vision, augmented-reality, aruco

I have ruler which is included on the picture below. The dimensions of the marker, color checker and space between the marker and the color checker are known.

[image]

The problem is how to compute position of the color checker's corners (C1-C4) from the coordinates of the aruco marker (M1-M4) when the image is taken under perspective so just multiplying vectors (M2-M1) and (M3-M2) by scalar computed from marker dimensions and color checker dimensions is not possible.

The implementation is in C++ using OpenCV but code is not necessary.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I tried to use perspective transform

```
const std::vector<cv::Point2f> ruler_inner_rect_real = {
    left_marker.at(0),
    left_marker.at(1),
    left_marker.at(2),
    left_marker.at(3)
};
const std::vector<cv::Point2f> RULER_INNER_RECT_IDEAL = {
    cv::Point2f(0, 0),
    cv::Point2f(this->marker_size, 0),
    cv::Point2f(this->marker_size, this->marker_size),
    cv::Point2f(0, this->marker_size),
};
cv::Mat tmat = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(ruler_inner_rect_real, RULER_INNER_RECT_IDEAL);
```

But this thing doesn't work because the RULER_INNER_RECT_IDEAL is in the zero position of the image/Mat. What are the correct coordinates to be used with the perspective transform?

Edit:
So with the help in comments I got the solution to get points C1-C4:

```
const std::vector<cv::Point2f> in = {
    cv::Point2f(this->marker_size+this->color_checker_position_mm.width, this->color_checker_position_mm.height),
    cv::Point2f(this->marker_size+this->color_checker_position_mm.width+this->color_checker_width, this->color_checker_position_mm.height),
    cv::Point2f(this->marker_size+this->color_checker_position_mm.width+this->color_checker_width, this->marker_size+this->color_checker_position_mm.height),
    cv::Point2f(this->marker_size+this->color_checker_position_mm.width, this->marker_size+this->color_checker_position_mm.height),
};
std::vector<cv::Point2f> out;
cv::perspectiveTransform(in, out, tmat.inv());
```

Comment: it's all just transformation matrices, transforming from one frame to another. rvec/tvec are encodings, not usable for composition. you need a translation in marker space. then you need to compose that with the marker pose (transforms into camera space, from marker space), in the right way.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I edited question - added what I tried with the perspective transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know "paper" coordinates of all rectangle corners, coordinates of black rect corners at the image and want to find color rect image coordinates?

In this case you can use OpenCV [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga20f62aa3235d869c9956436c870893ae) function to calculate perspective transformation matrix for black rect (and for whole image), then apply [perspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad327659ac03e5fd6894b90025e6900a7) to transform color rect corners.

Comment: Yes, I was thinging about that but I don't actually know the coordinates of the marker in other space, do I?

Comment: I added what I tried into the question.

Comment: Make grayscale, choose [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) to exclude gray(former color), so only black will present at the image, then [look for corners](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html)

Comment: No, you got me wrong. I know coordinates of the marker in the image but not in the second space. Or I do but not really :D What is the correct RULER_INNER_RECT_IDEAL from the question?

Comment: So you need to tie "paper" coordinates to the ruler?

Comment: I know the image coordinates of the marker, real life dimensions of the marker, color checker and distance between these two but I need the image coordinates of the color checker from that

Comment: I had re-read your question. Method should work, but for getting C1'-C4' at the image you have to calculate inverse matrix: `getPerspectiveTransform(RULER_INNER_RECT_IDEAL,ruler_inner_rect_real)`

Comment: Ahh, I was so focused to the vectors and scaling them that I completely forgot about just transforming real life points. I put solution to the question. Thank you for your help!